# How to set custom date programmatically using ng bootstrap & angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

Here I am trying to set a date programmatically using `ng-bootstrap` date picker

I tried some thing like this putting the custom date

```
this.model= {
  "year": 2018,
  "month": 8,
  "day": 15
}
```

I know it is not efficient way and there is one issue is that after selecting the giving the date picker is not navigating to that particular month.

Suppose If I choose 2nd jan 2018 then also it is staying in the current month it is not moving to jan. How can i solve these issues?

Below is my code & [stack blitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-11qnzw)

**.ts code**

```
model: NgbDateStruct;
  date: {year: number, month: number};
  constructor(private calendar: NgbCalendar){

  }

   selectToday() {
    this.model = this.calendar.getToday();
  }

  select(){
    this.model= {
  "year": 2018,
  "month": 8,
  "day": 15
}
```

**.html file**

```
<ngb-datepicker #dp [(ngModel)]="model" (navigate)="date = $event.next"></ngb-datepicker>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `[startDate]="model"` binding so you will always get to the page when updating model:

```
<ngb-datepicker #dp [(ngModel)]="model" [startDate]="model" (navigate)="date = $event.next"></ngb-datepicker>
```

Or you might navigate the calendar manually via `dp.navigateTo(model)` method:

```
<ngb-datepicker #dp [(ngModel)]="model" (navigate)="date = $event.next"></ngb-datepicker>

<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary mr-2" (click)="selectToday(dp)">Select Today</button>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary mr-2" (click)="select(dp)">Select Custom</button>
```

And in controller:

```
selectToday(dp) {
  this.model = this.calendar.getToday();
  dp.navigateTo(this.model);
}

select(dp){
  this.model = {
    "year": 2018,
    "month": 8,
    "day": 15
  }
  dp.navigateTo(this.model);
}
```

More about this: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview#navigation

Updated example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-knmpxc

Manual solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uvmjg4

Comment: how to can i set date pro grammatically the approach i followed is ok ?

Comment: see updated answer for much simpler solution. setting the date via `ngModel` is fine. afaik there is no other way than using their weird Date format instead of native Date (you could use serializer to get Date from it, but not to set it).

Answer (score 1):

Create NgbDate instance by,

```
date = new NgbDate(2020,19,2);
```

make this date as ngModel;

See https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api#NgbDate